# Gmail centers email signature when it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, signature

I have made an email signature for a client which works perfectly on everything except Gmail. When I try to use the signature in Gmail it somehow centers it. This is only on the browser version. When I view the signature in the mail app on the iPhone it looks good. When I send the signature to Gmail from, for example, Outlook it looks good too. A screenshot of the problem: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BTEy.png) .

I have no idea why this happens so I hope someone here has the answer for me. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>3-column layout</title>

</head>

<style type="text/css">
/* Client-specific Styles */

#outlook a {
padding: 0;
} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
body {
width: 100% !important;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
.ExternalClass {
width: 100%;
} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
   .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font,              .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%;
    } /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.  More on that:     http://www.emailonacid.com/forum/viewthread/43/ */
#backgroundTable {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100% !important;
line-height: 100% !important;
}
img {
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
border: none;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
a img {
border: none;
}
.image_fix {
display: block;
}
p {
margin: 0px 0px !important;
}
table td {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

/*##############################################*/
/*IPHONE STYLES*/
/*##############################################*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
table {
position: relative;
}

table[class="fluid-table"], td[class="fluid-cell"]{
width: 100% !important;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px!important;

}

}
</style>

<body style="padding:0; margin:0">
<!-- 
/*##############################################*/

3 column

/*##############################################*/
-->


<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td  align="left" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none; color:#000; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
            <span style="text-align: left; color: #9C1C27;font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">Voornaam en Achternaam</span><br>
            <span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #B5987F; font-weight: normal; font-style:italic; font-size: 12px;">Functie titel</span><br>
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 0px; width:100%; height:100%;">
        <a href="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/"><img src="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/img/logo.png" nosend="1" border="0" style="width:179px; height:111px;"  alt="De Leeuw Hides logo" title="De Leeuw Hides logo"></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>

<div class="block">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="left">
<tr>
  <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" align="left" class="fluid-table">
      <tr>

        <!-- Start of first column --> 

        <td><table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
            <tbody>

              <tr>
                <td width="175" align="left" style=" border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                    <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Nijmegen</strong><br>
                    Lindenhoutseweg 69<br>
                    6545 AH Nijmegen <br>
                    The Netherlands
                </td>   
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- End of first column --> 

          <!--[if mso]></td><td valign="top"><![endif]--> 

          <!-- Start of second column -->

          <table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
            <tbody>

              <tr>
                <td width="175" align="left" style="border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                    <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Winterswijk</strong><br>
                    Industrieweg 2a<br>
                    7102 DZ Winterswijk<br>
                    The Netherlands
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- End of second column --> 

          <!--[if mso]></td><td valign="top"><![endif]--> 

          <!-- Start of third column -->

          <table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td width="175" align="left" style="border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                        <a href="tel:0031-024-3775233" style="color:#B5987F;"><font>T:</font> 0031-024-3775233</a> <br>
                        F: 0031-024-3779316 <br>
                        <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="mailto:sales@deleeuwhides.nl">sales@deleeuwhides.nl</a><br>
                        <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="http://www.deleeuwhides.com">www.deleeuwhides.com</a>
                    </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- End of third column --></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="left" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:3px;" class="fluid-table">
       <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0 0 2px 0; height:1px; width:100%; background-color:#B5987F;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="left" class="fluid-table">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"bgcolor="#9C1C27" style="height:30px; width:100%; background-color:#9C1C27;"><img style="display:block; margin:auto; padding:8px 0 0 0;" src="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/img/slogan-footer.png" alt="slogan">
                    </td>
               </tr>
        </table>



   </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I fixed this by starting to build the code line for line in a new .html document. Testing it every time in Gmail until the centering would occur again, but it never did. So now it is working like it should!

Answer (score 0):

*Have you tried float left in your outer table which has a class of fluid-table?*

If that doesn't fix it, give the below a shot and let me know if it works.

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100%; max-width:600px;">[signature content here]</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have created a table with two columns, first column has max width of 600px and the second doesn't have a width. Place all the content into the first column. I have placed the style inline, you can move it to a class if you want to.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by applying **"margin:0 !important"** to the signature main container.